# How do I pull information from URL in PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Lets say the url is `http://example.com/product/3` and I only want to retrieve what is after `http://example.com/product/`. I found this, it echos the domain but how do I get the three. Its this method reliable? I'm using codeIgniter also.

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
$pageURL = 'http';
$pageURL .= "://";
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
$pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
} else {
$pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}
return $pageURL;
}
?>

<?php
echo curPageURL();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the URI class of the codeigniter API.

The base_url is segment zero, so in your case, products would be segment 1 and the id segment 2.

```
$product_id = $this->uri->segment(2)
```

As chetan mentioned this is clearly documented in the user guide.

Answer (score 4):

Use `$this->uri->segment(n)`. Documentation for it is here:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

For your code, you would use:

```
$curPageURL = $this->url->segment(2)
```

Edited: Fixed a bug in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use parse_url instead:
http://php.net/manual/es/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Sorry, didn't read you were using CI. Above comment should be helpful.